# using a pointer from a C++ object, to another C++ object, to modify member variables, from Lua

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

How do you get a reference to a C++ object, from another C++ object, inside a Lua script? I don't really know how to summarize that in words properly, so let me elaborate with a Lua example first:

```
function doSomething()
    compo = a:getComponent()
    compo:setVariable(0)
end
```

a is a C++ object, and the function getComponent returns a pointer:

```
// inside A.h
Component* A::getComponent();
```

It seems the problem is that `getComponent()` is passing a copy of the Component object to Lua, instead of a reference. I come across the same problem with every function that returns a pointer, Lua cannot modify the original object.

Object a seems to be working correctly, if I modify a variable from within Lua, it's outcome is mirrored in C++. Both A and component are bound to Lua already, as well as the required methods.

Am I missing something syntactically or is there more to it than that?

I am using luabind, Lua 5.1, and MinGW. Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT

Here is the luabind code. I summarized it because there's a bunch of other binds that have no relation to the problem:

```
luabind::class_<A>("A")
    .def("getComponent", &A::getComponent)
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough indirection yet, do you?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I do have a couple levels of indirection, but it appears otherwise cause I was trying to simplify the problem to its bare roots. Unless you meant that my wording was confusing, in that case, my bad, I tend to ramble.

Comment: It would help to show the Luabind code for `A`.

Comment: @LucDanton There you go, I just put it up

Comment: "*I come across the same problem with every function that returns a pointer, Lua cannot modify the original object.*" Can you show proof of that? Show [a short, *complete* program that exhibits this behavior.](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

Make a Lua wrapper for the "component" too. Then make `a:getComponent()` return the Lua object, not a real reference for the C++ object. Add any methods you need on that new wrapper object. If you have more "objects", rinse and repeat.

In short: for every object you want to manipulate from Lua, you will have to create a Lua wrapper. The only way around that is creating extra functions on the top level object, and calling those from Lua (`a:setComponentVariable(0)` instead of `a:getComponent()` + `compo:setVariable(0)`).